# How to make 4 columns across in ASP.NET MVC - How to make my current code suck less

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code, I'm trying to get a table with 4 columns across. If I run out of columns, create a new row and make 4 more coumns. rinse. lather. repeat.

```
<tbody>
<%
int i = 0;
foreach (ItmXtnMultimedia multimedia in ViewData.Model.ItmXtnMultimedia) {
  if (i%4 == 0 && i== 0)
  {
    %><tr><%
  }
  if (i%4 == 0 && i != 0)
  {
    %></tr><tr><%
  }
  %>                    
  <td><%= multimedia.ImgTag100 %></td>                            
  <%
  i++;
  } %>
```

It works, but it sucks. Is there something built in to the framework or an extension method I can use? I guess I could roll my own, but figured there had to be something out there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about a little refactor?

```
<%
foreach (ItmXtnMultimedia multimedia in ViewData.Model.ItmXtnMultimedia) {
  manageColumnsForMe( 4 )
  %><td><%= multimedia.ImgTag100 %></td><%
  } 
%>
```

And the put the other code in a function using a static variable to store i

You can reuse the same function with different number of columns

Answer (score 2):

This is a good place to create an extension method.  Here's some almost-compilable C# pseudocode:

```
public static void IDunnoWhatToCallThis<T>(
    this HtmlHelper me, 
    T[] items,
    int columns,
    Action headerTemplate,
    Action<T> itemTemplate,
    Action newRowTemplate,
    Action footerTemplate )
{
  headerTemplate();

  for(int i = 0;i < items.Length; i++)
  {
    if(i != 0 && i%columns == 0)
      newRowTemplate();

    itemTemplate(items[i]);
  }

  footerTemplate();
}
```

And here's an example in use:

```
<% Html.IDunnoWhatToCallThis(
  ViewData.Model.ItmXtnMultimedia,
  4,
  () => %><table><tr><%,
  (item) => %><td><%= item.ImgTag100 %></td><%,
  () => %></tr><tr><%,
  () => %></tr></table><%);%>
```

I LOVE helpers like this, mixing inline code, lambdas and markup.  Its like watching magic.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I popped the fir  out of the loop... (still smells though)

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <%
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (ItmXtnMultimedia multimedia in ViewData.Model.ItmXtnMultimedia) {

                        if (i%4 == 0)
                        {
                            %></tr><tr><%
                        }
                        %>                    
                        <td><%= multimedia.ImgTag100 %></td>                            
                        <%
                        i++;
                    } %>                    
                </tbody>
```

Comment: parser killed half my first comment. I took the first tr tag out of the the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the second if with else if.. Other than that, it's okay.

```
foreach (ItmXtnMultimedia multimedia in ViewData.Model.ItmXtnMultimedia) 
{
  if (i%4 == 0 && i== 0)
  {
      %><tr><%
  }
  else if (i%4 == 0 && i != 0)
  {
      %></tr><tr><%
  }
  %><td><%= multimedia.ImgTag100 %></td><%
  i++;
}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming ViewData.Model.ItmXtnMultimedia is a list of some sort:

```
<tbody>
<%
    for (int i = 0; i < ViewData.Model.ItmXtnMultimedia.Count; i++ )
    {
        %><tr><%
        for (int j = 0; i < 4; j++)
        {
            if (i < ViewData.Model.ItmXtnMultimedia.Count)
            {
                %><td><%= ViewData.Model.ItmXtnMultimedia[i].ImgTag100 %> %></td><%
            }
            else
            {
                %><td></td><%
            }
        }
        %></tr><%
    } 
%>
</tbody>
```

Still a mess of code, but maybe more readable?